# Assigning a method as an argument to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm assigning a method to a variable that is used as an argument in a method. I am expecting that method to return a `shop` but instead its just returning the method. Here is the method accepting the argument.

```
def create_amazon_client(marketplace, seller_id, auth_token, shop = :which_shop_method_to_use?)
    keys = which_amazon_keys_to_use?(marketplace, shop)
    MWS::FulfillmentOutboundShipment::Client.new()
end
```

and then here is the method itself:

```
def which_shop_method_to_use?
  if current_shop.nil?
    return current_shop_by_session
  else
    return current_shop
  end
end
```

what's getting passed in is just this symbol 'which_shop_method_to_use?'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Side note: `which_shop_method_to_use?` shouldn't have the question mark suffix. This is saved for methods returning truthy / falsey values. IMO better off as `def shop_method; current_shop || current_shop_by_session; end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what's getting passed in is just this symbol `:which_shop_method_to_use?`

Yes, because that's exactly what the code says. If you wanted the result of calling that method, call that method.

```
def create_amazon_client(marketplace, seller_id, auth_token, shop = which_shop_method_to_use?)
```

Comment: it might be worth noting that in doing this, the method (`which_shop_mehtod_to_use?`) does appear to get called each time you invoke `create_amazon_client`. Off the cuff I would've (erroneously, it appears, after a quick trial program) said that this code would eval the shop param when the file is first loaded and then be stuck with that first return value and that may be the gut feeling a fair number of people have that sends them off trying other means of using method return values as default param values

Comment: @SimpleLime: "does appear to get called each time you invoke create_amazon_client" - yes, just as intended.